# How to hide status bar when displaying tutorial pages in iOS7?

Tags: ios, xcode, statusbar

I followed the link [How To Create UIPageViewController Using Storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) to show the tutorial pages when my app is first installed or updated. Since I don't think it is fine to show status bar when showing these pages, I want to hide them during tutorial pages and show them again in main view controller. I have set the status bar to `None` of the `PageViewController` in the storyboard, but it is not working. Also I have tried to add the following code mentioned in some posts to `PageContentViewController.m` file. However, it does not work either.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Upon showing the tutorial you can use this code to hide the status bar and show it again when your tutorial is removed by setting `setStatusBarHidden:NO`.

Answer (score 0):

You can show your tutorial ViewController using [`presentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:).

The easiest workaround I've found is to wrap the view controller you want to present inside a navigation controller, and then present that view controller.

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

#### Advantages:

- No mucking with frames needed.
- Same code works on iOS 6 an iOS 7.
- Less ugly than the other workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your .plist file to `YES`.
Then use

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```

in every viewController to enable or disable the status bar.